# How can I call "event.preventDefault" on the "a" tag within the ".ul li"?

Tags: jquery

In my code block below, I want to call `event.preventDefault` on the `a` tag within the `.ul li`, so that on click of any list element, the `a` tag should not redirect to the page in its `href` attribute. I tried by doing `$this.find("a").preventDefault();` but that results in an error. How would I go about doing this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".ul li").on("click", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find("a").preventDefault();

        // switch all lists off 
        $(".selectedList, .checkedList").removeClass("selectedList, checkedList");
        // switch this list on  
        $this.addClass("selectedList, checkedList");
    });
});
```

Comment: To avoid issues i recommend to bind click on $('.ul li a'), and at the end of the function you will return false;. Of course, you have to modify a bit the code, but not too much. Just use $(this).parent(), which will get the <li> element

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**event.preventDefault**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) on event object not on `DOM` element. You can do the trick by adding event click event to a and calling `preventDefault`

```
$(".ul li a").click(function(event){    
     event.preventDefault();    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".ul li a").on("click", function(e)
{
    var $this = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".selectedList, .checkedList").removeClass("selectedList, checkedList");
    // switch this list on  
    $this.parent().addClass("selectedList, checkedList");//or parents('li')
});
```

and at end use `.parent` if `a` is direct child of `li` or use `.parents('li')` to add `class` to `parent li`.

**OR**

`closest('li')` will work fine.

Comment: What if the `<a>` isn't an immediate child of the `<li>` element?

Comment: what if it does..??? because OP used `$this.find("a")` that means `a` is child of `li`.

Comment: No, it means it's a descendant, which is different to being a child. If you have `<li><a href="#">some text</a></li>` then the `<a>` is a child; if you have `<li><p><a href="#">some text</a></p></li>` then the `<a>` is a descendant - the `.find()` function will find the `<a>` either way, because it checks all levels, not just one down. The `.parent()` function, however, only goes up a single level.

Comment: +1 for you....so OP can use `parents('li')` it may wrapped inside `<li><li><p><a>` then OP can use `.parent().parent()`....but we don't know thats why i added parent only...or use `closest('li')`

Comment: Looks OK to me now - `.closest()` would be my personal choice for getting a reference to the `<li>` element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) in the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/event-object/).

I think the addClass usage also is wrong, there should not be any `,` between the class names if you want to add/removed multiple classes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".ul li a").on("click", function(e) {
            var $this = $(this);
            e.preventDefault();

            // switch all lists off 
            $(".selectedList, .checkedList").removeClass("selectedList checkedList");
            // switch this list on  
            $this.addClass("selectedList checkedList");
        });
    });
```

Comment: There's no `e` defined in your code - need to give the parameter on the anonymous function a name.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass  event object`. preventDefault()` is for event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".ul li").on("click", function(evt) {
            var $this = $(this);
            evt.preventDefault(); // this should be like this. 

            // switch all lists off 
            $(".selectedList, .checkedList").removeClass("selectedList, checkedList");
            // switch this list on  
            $this.addClass("selectedList, checkedList");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just use the the a-elements for the click event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ul li a").on("click", function( e ) {
        var $this = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();

        // switch all lists off 
        $(".selectedList, .checkedList").removeClass("selectedList, checkedList");
        // switch this list on  
        $this.parent( 'li' ).addClass("selectedList, checkedList");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.preventDefault()` function belongs to the jQuery normalised `event` object which is passed to the event handler function as the first argument. Simply specify a name for the parameter on your anonymous function and use it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ul li").on("click", function(event) {
        var $this = $(this);
        event.preventDefault();

        // switch all lists off 
        $(".selectedList, .checkedList").removeClass("selectedList checkedList");
        // switch this list on  
        $this.addClass("selectedList checkedList");
    });
});
```

Due to event bubbling any `click` events triggered on the `<a>` element should also be handled by this event handler. Also note that when using the `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` functions the list of class names is space, not comma, separated - it should be `"selectedList checkedList"` not `"selectedList, checkedList"`, unless your class is `selectedList,`.